# Google column chart vAxis.minValue doesn't work with all zero values

Tags: google-visualization

I am running into a case where all the data is by default coming as zero. Something like this:

```
    function drawVisualization() {
  // Create and populate the data table.
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Year', 'Austria', 'Belgium', 'Czech Republic', 'Finland', 'France', 'Germany'],
    ['2003',  0,   0,       0,       0,   0,  0],
    ['2004',  0,   0,       0,       0,   0,  0],
    ['2005',  0,   0,       0,      0,   0,  0],
    ['2006',  0,   0,       0,       0,   0,  0],
    ['2007',  0,   0,       0,       0,   0,  0],
    ['2008',  0,   0,       0,       0,   0,  0]
  ]);

  // Create and draw the visualization.
  new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
      draw(data,
           {title:"Yearly Coffee Consumption by Country",
            width:600, height:400,
            hAxis: {title: "Year"},vAxis:{minValue:0,format:"#"}}
      );
}
```

If you copy above code and play around on google [playground](https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#column_chart) you will find that the graph is hard limiting the minimum value to -1.0. What I wanted is to start the vAxis from zero and pick only integral values. But it is not happening. 
I have also tried viewWindowMode but, it also couldn't solve the problem. Screenshot below of how it got rendered.[image]

Answer (score 22):

You can fix it using `viewWindow.min` option (*The minimum horizontal data value to render.*), like:

```
            vAxis: {
                minValue:0,
                viewWindow: {
                    min: 0
                }
            }
```

Comment: Not working for me, might be obsolete unfortunately

Comment: This did not work for me either with all zero values

Answer (score 5):

You nee to add max value in `viewWindow` and remove baseline by color it.

```
vAxis: {
  viewWindowMode: "explicit",   
  viewWindow: {min: 0,max:1}, 
  baseline:{
    color: '#F6F6F6'
  }
}
```

Comment: this is it for me, you need to set the max, *not just the min*, for anything to change

Answer (score 4):

This can be achieved by setting the viewwindow values.

```
    vAxis: { viewWindow: { min: 0 }, viewWindowMode: "explicit" }
```